# Mongodb query, result only specific elements into array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, object, jsonresult

I have one problem to result my query in mongodb.

I have one collection of documents like this: https://github.com/pedrualves/document/blob/master/school.js

I can search this document without problems using 
"pages": 32

But, I can't show the results like this:

```
{
"book": [
 {
  "pages": 32,
  "title": "a"
 },
 {
  "pages": 32,
  "title": "c"
 },
 {
  "pages": 32,
  "title": "d"
 }
]
}
```

Someone, could help me with this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved using Unwind from aggregate framework.
So I can split the array, group and filter.

```
db.'collection_name'.aggregate([
{ $unwind : "$students" },
{ $unwind : "$students.class" },
{ $unwind : "$students.class.book" },
{$match:{"students.class.book.pages":{$in:[32]}}},
{$group:
{
_id:'$students.name',
teste:{$push:'$students.class.book'}
}
}
])
```

Also, is possible to use the operator $redact